# How to forward declaration of classes in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, forward-declaration

Why forward declaration of A and B classes doesn't work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A, B;    

class A {
public:
    A() {
        new B();
    }
};

class B {
public:
    B() {
        new A();
    }
};

int main () {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
};
```

Compiler Error:

```
classes.cpp:4:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘,’ token
classes.cpp:4:10: error: aggregate ‘A B’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
classes.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
classes.cpp:9:7: error: expected type-specifier before ‘B’
classes.cpp:9:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘B’
classes.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
classes.cpp:22:14: error: conversion from ‘A*’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested
classes.cpp:23:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b’
```

Comment: Because you don't *have* any forward declarations?!

Comment: The definition of A references B and the definition of B references A.  You can forward declare to indicate A and B by simply using "class A;" and "class B;"

Comment: Also, half your code doesn't make sense, the other half doesn't compile, and the third half is terrible style.

Comment: @KerrekSB I forgot forward declaration. I have edited the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
};

class B
{
public:
    B();
};

A::A() { new B(); }    // terrible code, leaks, serves no purpose
B::B() { new A(); }    // likewise
```

Comment: +1 outstandingly simple demonstration of an infinite-allocation stack to an overflow. I *like* it =P

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm beginning to like this question as a fine collection of "things that can go wrong" :-) Everything has value, as the saying goes, even if it is as a bad example.

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaration doesn't work when you need to create an object.

Forward declaration creates an incomplete type. You cannot use it to declare a member, or a base class, since the compiler would need to know the layout of the type. You cannot define a function which takes the type as a parameter (by value) or returns it (by value).

What you can do with forward declaring a type.

1. You can declare a pointer or reference to the forward declared type.
2. Define functions which have pointers/references to the type as a parameter
3. Define functions which return a pointer/reference to the type
4. You can *prototype* a function which accepts the type as parameter
5. You can *prototype* a function which returns the type.

By the way, what you are trying to do will lead to infinite recursion.

Create an object of A -> A's constructor will create an object of B -> B's constructor will create an object of A -> A's constructor will create an object of B and so on and so forth till your program blows up.

Comment: I have compiled the @KerrekSB 's code, but the program will terminate!! why the program doesn't work properly? creating infinite recursion of object A and B?

Comment: @Khajavi - the program goes into infinite recursion for me and crashes.

Comment: @Khajavi: Run it in a debugger :-)

Comment: @user93353 Did the program memory leak? when did the program crash? after all memory is allocated? I have compiled it with GCC, after running the program Press ENTER or type command to continue "Command terminated" occur.

Comment: @Khajavi Put a `cout<<"In A Ctor\n";` in A's constructor and `cout<<"In B Ctor\n";` in B's constructor. Then you will know when it crashed. It crashed because you kept allocating memory.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create object the definition has to be known to the compiler. forward declaration yields incomplete type. you use forward declaration only to declare argument (declare functions or prototype) or return type of pointer or reference. you can just declare constructors and define them when objects definitions are known, as here:

```
class Aa {
public:
    Aa();
};

class Bb {
public:
    Bb();
};

Aa::Aa(){
    new Bb;//do something
}
Bb::Bb(){
    new Aa;//do something
}
```

and btw:
be careful about an infinite-allocation stack to an overflow...